# Automapper suddenly creates nested object

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Entities:

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class User : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Company Company { get; set; }
}

public class Company : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Dto's:

```
public class EntityDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class UserDto : EntityDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? CompanyId { get; set; }
}
```

So I want to map `User` to `UserDto` like `User.Company == null` `=>` `UserDto.CompanyId == null` and vice versa.

That is my **Automapper** configuration:

```
Mapper.Initialize(configuration =>
{
    configuration
        .CreateMap<User, UserDto>()
        .ReverseMap();
});
```

This works fine:

```
[Fact]
public void UnattachedUserMapTest()
{
    // Arrange
    var user = new User { Company = null };

    // Act
    var userDto = Mapper.Map<User, UserDto>(user);

    // Assert
    userDto.CompanyId.Should().BeNull();
}
```

but this test fails:

```
[Fact]
public void UnattachedUserDtoMapTest()
{
    // Arrange
    var userDto = new UserDto { CompanyId = null };

    // Act
    var user = Mapper.Map<UserDto, User>(userDto);

    // Assert
    user.Company.Should().BeNull();
}
```

Details:

```
Expected object to be <null>, but found 

Company
{
   Id = 0
   Name = <null>
}
```

Doesn't work for me:

```
...
.ReverseMap()
.ForMember(user => user.Company, opt => opt.Condition(dto => dto.CompanyId != null));
```

and well as that (just for example):

```
...
.ReverseMap()
.ForMember(user => user.Company, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Why does Automapper create nested object and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That "suddenly" bit is funny :)

```
configuration.CreateMap<User, UserDto>().ReverseMap().ForPath(c=>c.Company.Id, o=>o.Ignore());
```

You have a default MapFrom with CompanyId and that is applied in reverse. For details see [this](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2220) and a few other similar issues.

In the next version (on MyGet at the moment) you'll also be able to use

```
configuration.CreateMap<User, UserDto>().ReverseMap().ForMember(c=>c.Company, o=>o.Ignore());
```

Comment: So I suppose I am not able to use conditional mapping for member? Ignore is still ok for me, but I just want to know)

Comment: Yes, exactly. Nice to see it will be available soon.